# Is it possible to limit which DB users/logins are audit logged in EnterpriseDB

Tags: enterprisedb

I need to audit log database DML in EnterpriseDB, but only interactive DB users/logins (i.e. SQL client accesses), not accesses by system users/logins. I haven't been able to figure out if audit logging can be defined by users/loging. Alternatively, is there a way to archive or remove audit entries by users/logins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can.

```
ALTER USER carol SET edb_audit_statement = "none";
```